# Stripe prices sort by unit_amount

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have the following promise using node.js to fetch the pricing plans from Stripe:

```
 const prices = await stripe.prices.list({
  active: true,
  expand: ["data.product"],
});
```

Is it possible to get the data sorted by unit_amount right from the Stripe's list method?

Comment: “*Is it possible to get the data sorted by unit_amount right from the Stripe's list method?*” Can you clarify as to why you don’t just sort it in your code regardless of what order Stripe returns it to you?

Comment: @esqew I've sorted it, but it would be much more elegant if would be possible :) I'm more curious since I didn't found anything in the documentation about that.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe doesn't support custom ordering and their List APIs always return objects ordered by `created` with the most recent object first.

It's not possible to sort by amount and you'll have to ingest the data into your own system/database and sort on that side.